# Как использовать Drawing::Color в наследуемом классе без ошибки "Недопустимый неполный тип"?

Tags: c++-cli

Я хочу использовать указатель на системную структуру Drawing::Color в своём colorVS, наследуемом от моего же пустого класса color.

Класс color:

```
// color.h
class color
{
public:
    color()
    {
        ;
    }
};
```

Класс colorVS:

```
//colorVS.h
#include <vcclr.h>
#include <ddraw.h>
#include "color.h"

typedef System::Drawing::Color colorType;

class colorVS : public color
{
public:
    colorVS(colorType* nclr);
    colorType* getVS();
private:
    colorType* VScolor;
};
```

Однако в этом случае colorType* помечается как "Недопустимый неполный тип" и ничего не компилируются и не работает. При этом, если наследование colorVS от моего color убрать, всё прекрасно работает.

Возможно ли решить эту проблему и, если да, то как?

Answer (score 0):

В общем, запустил сегодня утром заново, после перезагрузки компьютера, Visual Studio и всё заработало. Похоже, это один из багов самой среды

П.С. Весь вечер вчера сидел, думал, а оказалась такая фигня...